# How to plot the stable and unstable manifold of a map, in python?

Tags: python, math, dynamic

I need to plot the stable and unstable manifold for the Henon map $x_{n+1} = 1 - ax_n^2 + y_n$ and $y_{n+1} = bx_n$, where $a$ and $b$ are parameters. For do this i know that i can chose an line of initial conditions along the directions of the eigenvectors of the Jacobian matrix evaluated in the fixed points positions. The problem is that i got no idea of how to do this, i'm very new to python or any programming language. I could do the initial conditions be in an line, but i do not know how they would be in the eigenvectors directions

```
def HenonMap(a,b,x,y):
return 1 - a*x**2 + y, b*x


from pylab import *
import numpy.linalg as LA
a = 1.4
b = 0.3
nIterates = 100
xlabel('x(n)') # set x-axis label
ylabel('y(n)') # set y-axis label

nICs = 10000
xmin = -6
xmax = 0.6
xinc = (xmax - xmin) / nICs
ymin =  -0.18
ymax =   0.18
yinc = (ymax - ymin) / nICs
x = []
y = []

for i in xrange(0,nICs):
    x.append(xmin + (xmax - xmin) * xinc * i)
    y.append(ymin + (ymax - ymin) * yinc * i)
for n in range(0,nIterates):
    for i in range(0,nICs):
        x[i], y[i] = HenonMap(a,b,x[i],y[i])
plot(x,y, '-r')
```

show()

Comment: Could you add some code showing that you've spent some effort with the problem?

Comment: Sorry, but i did very little, i add what i did, i only could do an line of initial conditions.